# HTTP server response 409 // Google web app

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

I'm having issues lately with my web app written in Google Apps Script.. From time to time it doesn't load properly and returns a 409 response.. It seems as it has no real reason, it's randomly. If I try to reload the page sometimes it loads properly, sometimes returns 409. The issue also just occurs some days and times. I can't figure out what can be the reason, the only thing I've noticed is that when the issue occurs also Google Apps Script Program seem to be slow / failing (for example takes longer than usual to save a file, sometimes fails on saving or showing logs etc).

[Screenshot from web inspector when the issue occurs..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZMy5.png)

If the issue is on Google's end on their servers I guess there's not much I can do, but still checking if anyone else experienced these issues? Or is there anything I can do?

Also want to make sure it's not in my code.. I'm not in anyway a pro when it comes to programming, but a happy amateur. But if it was in my code, at least in my mind it would fail every time and not just only sometimes? I googles a bit and found [on this site](http://techqa.info/programming/question/41734834/google-script-api-routexl-error-409) that when making POST requests you need to have your parameters correct, I'm using Twilio in my script but it's in a separate function and is not initiated when the script loads and I have it written as the linked documentation suggests..

Inserting some code snippets here - if anyone sees something that looks weird or could be the reason for my issues I would much appreciate your help!

SMS Function - can this be the reason??

```
function sendSms_(to, body) {
var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACe5***************/Messages.json";
var payload = {
"To": to,
"Body" : body,
"From" : "Killnoise"
};

var options = {
"method" : "post",
"contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", //This line I added after reading the linked documentation
"payload" : payload
};

options.headers = { 
"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("AC********************:f8be***************")
};
try { UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options); } catch(Err) {}
return;  
}
```

doGet function - anything wrong here??

```
 function doGet(e){
var staffId = e.parameter.staffId;
var key = e.parameter.key;
var lang = e.parameter.lang
// staffId = "S102", key = "abc"
if(auth_(staffId, key, lang) == true){
var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('StaffHtml').getRawContent();
/*/ 
Am I doing right above and below when the output is returned? I'm a bit green
here - should I write this in another way? Not seeing this could be the reason
for my current issue though..

/*/
output = output.replace('{{selectAlert}}', language('selectAlert', lang));
output = output.replace('{{takenAlert}}', language('takenAlert', lang));
output = output.replace('{{declineGivenAlert}}', language('declineGivenAlert', lang));
output = output.replace('{{beta}}', language('beta', lang));
output = output.replace(/{{surgePrompt}}/g, language('surgePrompt', lang));
output = output.replace('<%staffId%>', lang + staffId);
output = output.replace('{{invitationSent}}', language('invitationSent', lang));
output = output.replace('{{timeOutAlert}}', language('timeOutAlert', lang));
output = output.replace('{{newNotifications}}', language('newNotifications', lang));


var out = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output)
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no')
  .setTitle('Killnoise').setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.DEFAULT);
  return out;
} else {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Invalid URLS');
}
}
```

Comment: I would try putting some more error checking around `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile` to make sure that it was able to load your template. If it wasn't able to for some reason then you may get errors like that if your output is empty.

Comment: Thanks @Andy - I for sure should check over my doGet as I see myself how horrible it looks but it's not the source of the issue.. The page loads, it's when the DOM is manipulated after load it get's caught up.. Starting to think it's something with Googles servers.. Loading Script Editor just took me three reloads...

Comment: Ah fair enough. Good luck!

Comment: See the issue tracker for this problem:  [Link to Issue Tracker - 409 bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62013415)

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood - there we go! That's exactly what I looked for! Then I know it's not just me and my script - feels good..